# Using system.time in R, getting very varied times

Tags: r

I have written two functions in R and I need to see which is faster so I used system.time. However, the answers are so varied I can't tell. As its for assessed work I don't feel I can actually post the code (in case someone corrects it). Both functions call rbinom to generate multiple values and this is the only part that isn't a simple calculation.

The function time needs to be as fast as possible but both are returning times of anywhere between 0.17 and 0.33. As the mark is 0.14/(my function time) x 10 it's important I know the exact time.

I have left gcFirst=TRUE as recommended in the R help.

My question is why are the times so inconsistent? Is it most likely to be the functions themselves, my laptop or R?

Comment: It is all of the above.  If you were to run a 100m dash 10 times, you would get different results each time too.  There are lots of things that influence the computers speed.  As Dirk mentioned below, one of the benchmarking packages is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use one of the benchmarking packages

- [rbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rbenchmark)
- [microbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/package=microbenchmark)

for this.  And even then, variability will always enter. Benchmarking and performance testing is not the most exact science.

Also see the parts on profiling in the "Writing R Extensions" manual.